# How do I click the first link in a list using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-nikeid-shoes/7puZoolZoi3

I am trying to click the first shoe listed in the store.  I need to know how to reliably click the first shoe, as the store inventory changes daily, so I'm worried that if I write this myself without checking, the script could break when the shoe inventory changes.

Should I be using xpath or css_selector?

How do I do correctly do:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("firstshoe").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following CSS selector would match all products (shoes) on the page:

```
.grid-item.nikeid
```

And if you use `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".grid-item.nikeid").click()` - you would click the first shoe on the page.

Comment: Do you think it is a smart idea to use use 'wait' for every element i am clicking?  Is that standard practice?  I ask because sometimes my test errors out when the page elements do not load in time.

Comment: @Ben yeah, waits, on one hand complicate the code, but on the other they make the code more stable.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use below XPath to find the first link in the grid

```
//*[contains(@class,'grid-item')]/a)[1]
```